# How do I read a JSON string in Python/Windows when the string contains non-UTF8 characters?

Tags: python, windows, json, unicode

I think I need to call json.loads() with the character encoding set to something other than utf-8 which I understand is the default.

Can someone tell me where I can find out how to do this please? I have googled but I get lost in the technical stuff eg the JSON RFC.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's something I'm missing from your question:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads
The second argument to `loads` is the name of the encoding.

Comment: Thank you all. I must be getting tired.

Answer (score 0):

It's right in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

> If s is a str instance and is encoded with an ASCII based encoding other than UTF-8 (e.g. latin-1), then an appropriate encoding name must be specified.

So use the `encoding` argument to `loads`.